# Providing action parameter value in struts-config in Struts1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts1

Just as in Struts2 we can provide a parameter value in struts.xml as below

```
<action name="myS2Action" class="demo.myS2Action">
    <result>/myS2Page.jsp</result>
    <param name="myS2Param">value</param>
</action>
```

In Struts1, Is there any way to set some parameter value in struts-config.xml?

I have following entries in struts-config.xml

```
<form-bean name="myS1Form" type="demo.MyS1Form"></form-bean>
<action path="/myS1Action" type="demo.myS1Action" name="myS1Form" scope="request" >
    <forward name="success" path="/myS1Page.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Strut1 configuration, we can use `set-property` tag. Following question is related to usage of `set-property` tag.

[In Struts1, how to use set-property tag inside action tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13248696/1307229)