# In Struts1, how to use set-property tag inside action tag?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, struts1

I want to pass a value in action when it is called using struts1 configuration file. I have create a form bean with following property

```
public class MyForm extends ActionForm {
    private String task;  

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }
    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
}
```

In struts-config.xml, I have defined form bean and action as below.

```
<form-bean name="myForm" type="demo.MyForm"></form-bean>
<action path="/myAction" name="myForm" type="demo.MyAction" scope="request">
    <set-property value="view" property="task" />
    <forward name="success" path="/result.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

I am trying to run it in web sphere 6.1 with these configurations, it gives following exception

```
Deregister the mbean because of uncaught init() exception thrown by servlet action: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Parsing error processing resource path file:/D:/workspaces/j-space/myProject/Web Content/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.handleConfigException(ActionServlet.java:761)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:744)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:689)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:356)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
....
```

I think I am missing something or using set-property tag in wrong way . Can anyone help?

Comment: `set-property` is child of `form-bean`, not `action`

Comment: `set-property` is also child of `action`.

Comment: hope this link will guide you better http://www.mail-archive.com/struts-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg21396.html

Comment: I also tried `<set-property value="view" key="task" />`. Now exception is not occurring, but value of `task` is `null`.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks Rajesh. Please place this link as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Struts 1.3 DTD](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/struts-core/dtddoc/index.html) says

> The "set-property" element is especially useful when a custom subclass
>   is used with , , , or 
>   elements.

Create Subclass of ActionMapping with properties you would like to inclide

```
public class CustomActionMapping extends ActionMapping {

    private String task;

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(String task) {
        this.task = task;
    }
}
```

configure the custom action mapping in `struts-config.xml`

```
<action-mappings type="CustomActionMapping">
   <action path="/myAction" name="myForm" type="demo.MyAction" scope="request">
      <set-property value="view" property="task" />
      <forward name="success" path="/result.jsp"></forward>
   </action>
</action-mappings>
```

get the value of task in `doGet/doPost` method your `Action` class

```
CustomActionMapping cam = (CustomActionMapping) mapping;
String task = cam.getTask();
```

hope this helps you.

Comment: How to access this property in JSP ?

Comment: [In Struts1, How to access ActionMapping parameter in JSP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13265710/1307229)

Answer (score -1):

Does your struts-config.xml follow the schema?
See sample on http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/index.html

Comment: yes... it follows the schema... it works fine when set-property tag is not used.