# In Struts1, How to access ActionMapping parameter in JSP

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, struts1

Proceeding from the question

[In Struts1, how to use set-property tag inside action tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13248696/1307229)

When `set-property` tag is used, its value is mapped to property in extended ActionMapping class. Is there any way to access this property in JSP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `bean:struts` tag:

```
<bean:struts id="myActionMapping" mapping="/myAction" />
```

Once defined, you can access the properties straight on the `myActionMapping` JSP bean:

```
<bean:write name="myActionMapping" property="task" />
```

Or, using EL:

```
${myActionMapping.task}
```

Reference: [struts-bean.tld](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-bean.tld)